# JMeter: How do I upload an Image file in JMeter?

Tags: file, download, upload, jmeter, mime

I have a scenario where its required to upload 10,000 image files. File path is 
**D:\ImagesToBeUploaded\Images**

I would like to know what input should I provide to **Parameter Name** and "File Path" in HTTP Request.

Can a File Path be: D:\ImagesToBeUploaded\Images

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The information you have provide is really not enough to tell what your solution is but why don't you check what BlazeMeter says about [uploading files](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) and about the MIME Type try [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)

Comment: I went through the link but still did not understand what would be the input for "Value" if I am uploading image file locally from D Drive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a excel csv file.
2. open cmd and navigate to images directory. run dir command.

3.copy file names to csv file's A column.

4. Open jmeter, set thread for  running forever, add csv to your project and give your csv path. Give a variable name for your column.
5. Add your variable name to http request file upload part. fix the url with full path.
6. set your csv control for break test at the end of file.